# Linq distinct count

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data returned as the follow:

```
Model { Guid Id }
```

and I have an int of the total items, `int totalCount`.

I am trying to get the distinct count from the data that were returned as Category 1,
and have the total item minus the count from Category 1 to be Category 2.

I have the following linq to get the distinct count for Category 1, but how do I add the count for Category 2 into the IEnumerable?

```
var result = data.
    GroupBy(x => x.Id).
    Select(x => new { Category = "1", Value = x.Select(v => v.Id).Distinct().Count() }).
    GroupBy(x => x.Category).
    Select(x => new Item { Category = x.Key, Value = x.Sum(y => y.Value) });
```

and the Item Class have 2 members: string for Category and decimal for Value.

Thanks!

---

Edit:
So I have the follow data `IEnumerable<Model> data`, and it contains the following data:

```
{ Id: 1 }
{ Id: 2 }
{ Id: 2 }
{ Id: 1 }
{ Id: 3 }
{ Id: 4 }
```

and totalCount = 10.

I would like to get the distinct count of Id from data, which is 4 in this case, as category 1, and totalCount - distinct item to be category 2. So for the result I will have a `IEnumerable` of `Item` to have the following:

```
{ Category: "1", Value: 4 }, { Category: "2", Value: 6 }
```

For now my linq statement only return `{ Category: "1", Value: 4 }`, and I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Some simple sample data might help. In your code, The Count() method will always return 1. You are in context of items grouped by ".Id". Therefore there will only be one distinct .Id per group.
I suspect that your problem would be solved if you grouped by x.Category=="1". This would give you one "false" group and one "true" group, which you could distinct one respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I just edited the original question with some sample data. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I think this is what you want:

```
int totalCount = data.Count();
int distinctCount = data.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().Count();
List<Item> result = new List<Item>
{
    new Item() { Category = "1", Value = distinctCount },
    new Item() { Category = "2", Value = totalCount - distinctCount },
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I overcomplicated the problem since I am fairly new to LINQ. I was trying to do it with just one LINQ statement but I can definitely do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need two objects at the end of the day, or can it just be part of one return? You could just do:

```
var result = data.
    GroupBy(x => x.Id).
    Select(x => new { 
       DistinctCount = x.Select(v => v.Id).Distinct().Count(),
       TotalCount = data.Count()
    });
```

This or something similar would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I use the data structure to face the situation.

```
Dictionary< string, List< YOUR_TYPE >> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List< YOUR_TYPE >> ();
```

We can get different keys from source.

```
var keys = YOUR_DATA_SOURCE.Select(item => item.YOUR_KEY_NAME ).Distinct();
```

Just like SQL : "SELECT DISTINCT YOUR_KEY_NAME FROM YOUR_DATA_SOURCE".

```
foreach (var key in keys) {
    var list = new List< YOUR_TYPE > ();
    list.AddRange (dataSource.Where (x => x.YOUR_Filter_Property == YOUR_KEY_NAME ).ToList ());

    dictionary.Add (key, list);
}
```

Then we can use Dictionary's default features, like "ContainKey", "Keys" to help us.